# Can`t get libdl.so

Tags: games

After installing MangoHud and GOverlay everything works fine for Vulkan but I get the "Can't get libdl.so" when trying "mangohud glxgears"

New to Linux so I'm trying Ubuntu on a VM to learn the ropes before I switch to Linux as my PC's OS.

Answer (score 2):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/ allows you to search through package contents to find a missing file.

Using this search, you can see [libdl.so](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libdl.so) is contained within the package `libc6-dev`

To install:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y libc6-dev
```

Comment: I tried this but trying mangohud glxgears gives me the same error. I might try a fresh install VM maybe I did something wrong while messing around idk.